# Google AppEngine Pipelines API

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to rewrite some of my tasks as pipelines. Mainly because of the fact that I need a way of detecting when a task finished or start a tasks in specific order. My problem is that I'm not sure how to rewrite the recursive tasks to pipelines. By recursive I mean tasks that call themselves like this:

```
class MyTask(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        cursor = self.request.get('cursor', None)

        [set cursor if not null]
        [fetch 100 entities form datastore]

        if len(result) >= 100:
            [ create the same task in the queue and pass the cursor ]

        [do actual work the task was created for]
```

Now I would really like to write it as a pipeline and do something similar to:

```
class DoSomeJob(pipeline.Pipeline):

   def run(self):
       with pipeline.InOrder():
          yield MyTask()
          yield MyOtherTask()
          yield DoSomeMoreWork(message2)
```

Any help with this one will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve it with the pipeline API or used any other approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A basic pipeline just returns a value:

```py
class MyFirstPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):
    def run(self):
        return "Hello World"
```

The value has to be JSON serializable.

If you need to coordinate several pipelines you will need to use a *generator pipeline* and the `yield` statement.

```py
class MyGeneratorPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):
    def run(self):
        yield MyFirstPipeline()
```

You can treat the yielding of a pipeline as if it returns a ['future'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises).

You can pass this future as the input arg to another pipeline:

```py
class MyGeneratorPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):
    def run(self):
        result = yield MyFirstPipeline()
        yield MyOtherPipeline(result)
```

The Pipeline API will ensure that the `run` method of `MyOtherPipeline` is only called once the `result` future from `MyFirstPipeline` has been resolved to a real value.

You can't mix `yield` and `return` in the same method. If you are using `yield` the value has to be a Pipeline instance. This can lead to a problem if you want to do this:

```py
class MyRootPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):
    def run(self, *input_args):
        results = []
        for input_arg in input_args:
            intermediate = yield MyFirstPipeline(input_arg)
            result = yield MyOtherPipeline(intermediate)
            results.append(result)
        yield results
```

In this case the Pipeline API just sees a **list** in your final `yield results` line, so it doesn't know to resolve the futures inside it before returning and you will get an error.

They're not documented but there is a library of utility pipelines included which can help here:
https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/source/browse/trunk/src/pipeline/common.py

So a version of the above which actually works would look like:

```py
import pipeline
from pipeline import common

class MyRootPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):
    def run(self, *input_args):
        results = []
        for input_arg in input_args:
            intermediate = yield MyFirstPipeline(input_arg)
            result = yield MyOtherPipeline(intermediate)
            results.append(result)
        yield common.List(*results)
```

Now we're ok, we're yielding a pipeline instance and Pipeline API knows to resolve its future value properly. The source of the `common.List` pipeline is very simple:

```py
class List(pipeline.Pipeline):
    """Returns a list with the supplied positional arguments."""

    def run(self, *args):
        return list(args)
```

...at the point that *this* pipeline's `run` method is called the Pipeline API has resolved all of the items in the list to actual values, which can be passed in as `*args`.

Anyway, back to your original example, you could do something like this:

```py
class FetchEntitites(pipeline.Pipeline):
    def run(self, cursor=None)
        if cursor is not None:
            cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=cursor)

        # I think it's ok to pass None as the cursor here, haven't confirmed
        results, next_curs, more = MyModel.query().fetch_page(100,
                                                              start_cursor=cursor)

        # queue up a task for the next page of results immediately
        future_results = []
        if more:
            future_results = yield FetchEntitites(next_curs.urlsafe())

        current_results = [ do some work on `results` ]

        # (assumes current_results and future_results are both lists)
        # this will have to wait for all of the recursive calls in
        # future_results to resolve before it can resolve itself:
        yield common.Extend(current_results, future_results)
```

### Further explanation

At the start I said we can treat `result = yield MyPipeline()` as if it returns a 'future'. This is not strictly true, obviously we are actually just yielding the instantiated pipeline. (Needless to say our `run` method is now a *generator* function.)

The weird part of how Python's **[yield expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions)** work is that, despite what it looks like, the value that you `yield` goes somewhere *outside* the function (to the Pipeline API apparatus) rather than into your `result` var. The value of the `result` var on the left side of the expression is also pushed in from *outside* the function, by calling `send` on the generator (the generator being the `run` method you defined).

So by yielding an instantiated Pipeline, you are letting the Pipeline API take that instance and call its `run` method somewhere else at some other time (in fact it will be passed into a task queue as a class name and a set of args and kwargs and re-instantiated there... this is why your args and kwargs need to be JSON serializable too).

Meanwhile the Pipeline API `send`s a `PipelineFuture` object into your `run` generator and this is what appears in your `result` var. It seems a bit magical and counter-intuitive but this is how generators with yield expressions work.

It's taken quite a bit of head-scratching for me to work it out to this level and I welcome any clarifications or corrections on anything I got wrong.

Comment: Super explanation. Pipeline API is wonderful but docs are terrible. This is a very useful example of how to construct a complex- ish pipeline, one where you don't know in advance how many (or when) results are likely to be returned, ie have to spawn tasks recursively

Comment: if you're using Pipeline API seriously in a project it's worth bearing in mind that Google don't seem to be supporting the Python version, only the Java side has any activity in terms of issues and commits. Also the status UI is basically completely broken. I have been using this fork which addresses some of the problems and at least seems actively developed: https://github.com/Khan/appengine-mapreduce

Comment: I just hope they don't somehow deprecate the files API it seems to depend on for JSON serialisation. Then we're in serious trouble.

Comment: Perhaps you could help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883652/retrying-a-python-app-engine-pipeline

Comment: @Justin for your FilesAPI comment, I have to agree. You can see that it's been reported https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-pipelines/issues/53. Mabe it'll get some traction :)

Comment: @Anentropic, where should we define future_results? It gives me the error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'future_results' referenced before assignment" at the common.Extend line. I've done some logging and I am sure common.Extend is called after all the recursion is ended. By the way, this is the only example for the pipeline API cursor loop on the internet I guess, thank you!

Comment: ah I see it is only defined inside the `if more:` block which is a mistake, will update the answer now

Comment: Actually It was working without it, too. I am at the head-scratching stage for 2 days now to solve the recursion with pipeline API and really confused. 

How can we tell the recursion has ended and future results are ready for the next stage on the flow? I mean we've fetched the entities recursively and now we want to email the team about it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: when you instantiate a pipeline `p = MyPipeline(some_future)` you can pass a future as arg, but inside the pipeline's `run` method that arg will have been resolved into a real result... so put your email code into the `run` method of a pipeline that receives the results of everything before it

Comment: in the example above that would mean either sub-classing `common.Extend` or you could make a dedicated extra pipeline step at the end eg `final_result = common.Extend(future_results)` `yield SendEmailPipeline(final_result)`

Comment: Hello, if I do that I receive the below error; 

TypeError: pipeline.common.Extend(*(<pipeline.pipeline.PipelineFuture object at 0x109b424d0>,), **{}) is not JSON serializable

Full code here; http://paste.openstack.org/show/478509/

Without line 29 and 30 it works okay and prints the current and future results as expected. Still couldn't figure out how to go on after recursion is over.

Comment: Made a little change and now it works; http://paste.openstack.org/show/478523/

But emailTeam method is called many times (as many as recursion count), so how can I get it to called once? Sorry bothering you with a lot of questions but there is not so many examples and documentation about it :/

Comment: see my reply paste http://paste.openstack.org/show/478550/ (written off the top of my head, not tested!)  basically you need to have another 'layer' of pipeline to wrap the recursing part and collect just the final results

Answer (score 3):

When you create a pipeline, it hands back an object that represents a "stage". You can ask the stage for its id, then save it away. Later, you can reconstitute the stage from the saved id, then ask the stage if it's done.

See http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted and look for `has_finalized`. There's an example that does most of what you need.

Comment: It would be really helpful if they did more documentation on recursive tasks and the way of collecting data when they finish.