# When are tasks created by Google App Engine Pipelines API

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue, urlfetch

What are the under-the-hood details when it comes to starting a Pipeline like this (just a copy paste example line from the demo code of Pipelines API):

`split_counts = yield SplitCount(entity_kind, property_name, *value_list)`

Will a `yield` just enqueue one (1) task to the task queue, or is Pipelines handling this internally using different amount of tasks for each Pipeline on its "own" according to the job being done?

The context of the question:
Solving the job from scratch keeping full control using a combination of task queues, async url fetches, memcache, backends/modules, hence controlling all specifics about the tasks and the corresponding task queues being used;

or,

just rely on Pipelines.

Comment: I am wondering the same thing, the documentation is very limited about this. I mean, I have some pipelines running (async), but I really don't understand where they are run. Did you find out anything?

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline api will basically enqueue a single 'run' task when you yield a Pipeline instance.

However when your yielded pipeline returns there may be an additional 'output' task enqueued to forward the results to any downstream pipelines depending on them (and 'run' them)... there's also a 'fanout' task involved in this somehow.

When the whole pipeline chain has run there will be another 'finalized' task enqueued for each of the constituent pipelines.

Have a look down the bottom of pipeline.py where the request handlers are defined.

And of course any of these can be enqueued more than once, as for any task on the GAE task queue, and if any uncaught exception is raised by your pipeline instance when run then the task will be retried.

Some more detail (not specifically about tasks, more me trying to understand the yield expressions involved) here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25620665/202168

Answer (score -3):

In short, you most likely need [Task Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/), memcache, async url fetches and so on as you mention.  Yields and pipelines have nothing to do with task queues, they manage a form of coroutine that cannot of itself perform any of the aforementioned operations.

To try to eliminate some apparent confusion:  A yield does not create a task.  A pipeline is not a task queue.  [Yield expressions](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) are Python language constructs that do not depend on AppEngine.  In contrast a task is an AppEngine record in a data structure (the queue) that the AppEngine runtime uses to start a new background process (not serving a browser request) that is allowed to run for up to 10 minutes.  Any process including a background task may optionally use yields to manage flow control within just that process.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware of the content in your answer, and I am asking about when tasks are created by the Pipelines API. The Python snippet above was just a starting point for the question. The purpose of the question is to get a good overview over the number of tasks the Pipelines API is creating and when. What determines task spawning by the Pipelines API?

Comment: Where is this Pipelines API of which you write, so that I may better understand what you mean?