# Retrying a python App Engine pipeline

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a client pipeline which needs to post a request to an external calculation server, then retrieve the results. The calculation takes some time, so the external server processes it in a task queue. The client pipeline isn't exactly sure when the results will be ready; instead it needs to poll the server (get_status(id)), then if status==Completed retrieve the results (get_results(id))

Problem is that occasionally the server calculation fails, in which case I need the client pipeline to retry. I have a pipeline pattern based on this post:

[Google AppEngine Pipelines API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365172/google-appengine-pipelines-api)

which looks as follows:

```
class ReducePipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def run(self, *args):
        results=[result for result in list(args)
                 if result]
        if results==[]:
            return None
        return results[0]

class CallbackPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def run(self, id):
        status=get_status(id) # call external server status
        results, future_results = None, None
        if status==Error:
            pass    
        elif status==Completed:
            results=get_results(id) # get results from external server
        elif status!=Completed:
            with pipeline.InOrder():
                yield Delay(seconds=CallbackWait) # NB
                future_results=yield CallbackPipeline(id)
        yield ReducePipeline(results, future_results)

class StartPipeline(pipeline.Pipeline):

    def run(self, request):
        id=start(request) # post request to external server; get job id in return
        yield CallbackPipeline(id)

    """
    is this really the best way to retry the pipeline ? dev_appserver.py results don't look promising :-(
    """

    def finalized(self):
        if not self.outputs.default:
            raise pipeline.Retry()
```

but this doesn't seem to work on dev_appserver.py, simply causing repeated errors at the StartPipeline finalisation stage. I was hoping to get the entire StartPipeline to retry instead.

Can anyone advise me on a sensible pattern for retrying the StartPipeline on receipt of None results ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have never used them but this seems like a good fit for "Asynchronous pipelines" https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/wiki/GettingStarted#Asynchronous_pipelines in which case I think you would not necessarily do the polling within a pipeline, maybe from a taskqueue task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely need a 4th pipeline that interprets, validates and confirms that the results of CallbackPipeline are what you need and you'll need to raise the Retry from within the run() of that new pipeline.

You could also use recursion in that 4th pipeline versus raising a Retry.  You'd simply keep calling the CallbackPipeline until you did achieve the results you were looking for.  This would need to be done asynchronously, like Anentropic posted above.